# Adding Laravel, JQuery and Bootstrap to existing PHP Project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I want to add Laravel, JQuery and Bootstrap to an existing (custom written) PHP project. What the correct order to do this? Is it the one above or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is PHP framework, jQuery is javascript library. They do not interfere. Bootstrap is CSS framework generally. If you're planning to use bootstrap javascript, you should include jQuery to HTML page before `bootstrap.js` file, because all bootstrap plugins depend on jQuery.
Otherwise if you want to use only `bootstrap.css`. Order doesn't matter at all

Comment: I'd like to start by adding `bootstrap` to the project (to make it pretty) but if I do that and then convert it to Laravel later will I have to redo any of the `bootstrap` work?

Comment: Basically, /*adding*/ laravel to existing PHP project means /*rewriting*/ it using laravel. It shouldn't discard your work on templates, but it could be difficult. I advise you to start with reimplementing logic first and perform some prettifying after.

Comment: I guess that's what I was asking. If I'm looking at a rewrite for `Laravel` then it seems pointless to do a load of work on adding `bootstrap` now.